# compile: version "go1.9" does not match go tool version "go1.9.1"

Tags: go

I am getting this error when I tried to run an example helloworld code I got onlie.

```
compile: version "go1.9" does not match go tool version "go1.9.1"
```

My computer has go1.9.1. What does the error mean and how can I fix this?

Comment: You have something wrong with your Go installation. Either you have GOROOT set when it shouldn't be, you are invoking the wrong `go` binary, or the source in `GOROOT` doesn't match the tools and they need to be recompiled.

Comment: when you update Go remember delete **/usr/local/go** folder

Comment: You should post the result of `go env`.

Comment: In my case IntelliJ IDEA / Golang IDE set `GOROOT` to a previous version of Go installed by homebrew.

Comment: I am getting this in Ubuntu: => compile: version "go1.13.8" does not match go tool version "go1.16.5"

Comment: I had this issue and found that my /usr/bin/go was linked to a go binary different than /usr/local/go/bin/go. I had to `rm /usr/bin/go` and `ln -s /usr/local/go/bin/go /usr/bin/go`

Answer (score 66):

If you are installing using OSX homebrew you may need to set the `$GOROOT` in your `.bashrc`, `.zshrc`, etc:

```
export GOROOT=/usr/local/opt/go/libexec
```

I had the same error this morning when I updated from 1.9 -> 1.9.1 though according to several post the `$GOROOT` shouldn't have to be set and I had not set it until today. <strike>This may be a bug?</strike>

Edit: not a bug, for more details see [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53661370/1490379).

Comment: I faced this problem after a brew update.
To fix it I installed the old version using the command:  `brew link go@1.14`
And after that a changed the `GOROOT` value to:
`GOROOT=/usr/local/opt/go@1.14/libexec`

Comment: In my case I got a new laptop. I copied all my code and bashrc and other such files ontor my new laptop so that I could leverage the same aliases/vars etc. I think the go installation was done freshly on the new laptop and so this path didn't match up. This solution helped.

Answer (score 38):

This is a mismatch between the `GOROOT` environment variable and the default path to your `go` command. One or the other needs to be changed; the one that needs to be changed depends on the specific setup on your computer. You could determine this by updating your Go to the latest version using your preferred method, running either `which go` (on Linux/macOS/BSD) or `where go` (on Windows), and then checking which of the files listed has the newer timestamp.

### Linux/macOS/BSD

- To change the `GOROOT` to match the default path of your `go` command, run `type go` and strip off the `/bin/go` part at the end to yield the directory path containing your Go installation. Then, add it to your `.bashrc` or other appropriate init file like this:

`export GOROOT=/path/to/go-installation`

- To instead change the `go` command path to match your `GOROOT`, add this to the bottom of your init file:

`export PATH="${GOROOT}/bin:${PATH}"`

### Windows

- To change the `GOROOT` to match the default path of your `go` command, run `where go` take the first line of output, and strip off the `\bin\go.exe` part at the end. Then, go to "Edit the system environment variables" in Settings, click "Environment Variables...", find the "GOROOT" variable and edit to read the path you created earlier.
- To instead change the `go` command path to match your `GOROOT`, first save the output of `echo %GOROOT%\bin`. Then, go to "Edit the system environment variables" in Settings, click "Environment Variables...", and find the 
  find the "Path" row in the bottom pane, click New, put in the path you created earlier, and finally click Move Up until it's at the top.

### All

You'll need to open up a new command prompt to see the effects.

Comment: The second option in macOS section worked for me and thanks for the good explanation as well.

Comment: In my case, I believe Fedora 37 updates installed the new version go in a different location. 
I had it at `/usr/local/go/` and the new location is `/usr/lib/golang`
Updating GOROOT to new location worked as suggested.

Answer (score 19):

in case you are using mac with homebrew, just run:

`brew cleanup`

to clean all the legacy package, this fixed my problem.

Comment: That worked! But I also needed to manually remove package files with read-only permissions set: `chmod -R +w  /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.17/pkg/*; rm -fR /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.17`

Answer (score 14):

In mac OS , if you downloaded and installed go package without brew, running brew update commands will cause this problem to occur
for fix this problem you can do :
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies go
uninstalling go from brew will fix problem

Comment: This should be upvoted more. I had this happen to me while i was following instructions while learning go from book "Learning Go" and I got to the section on Linting and Vetting; the tool `golangci-lint` is installed using brew, or at least that's what you're told to do. That killed my Go setup. Uninstalling as Mohammad suggests fixed it perfectly for me. I just use Goland and basic Linter, works fine. Extra linter is not worth the hassle.

Answer (score 9):

For M1 Mac, the following steps helped me!

Check for which go from VSCode Terminal and check from system terminal.

from vscode terminal

```
user@mac % which go
/usr/local/go/bin/go
```

from my mac terminal

```
user@mac % which go
/opt/homebrew/bin/go
```

Whichever corresponds to the GOROOT shown go env, keep it and delete the other one

```
user@mac % go env GOROOT
/usr/local/go
```

in this case

```
rm -rf /opt/homebrew/bin/go
```

close and reload the vscode and terminal

Comment: This worked lika a charm

Answer (score 5):

This error happens when you forgot to delete previous golang install ... just delete its directory ... so identify go install location ... on linux issue

```
type go
```

typical output is

```
go is hashed (/usr/local/go/bin/go)
```

so just remove its grandparent directory ( go install dir not just the go binary )

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/go   #  NOTE this is not /usr/local/go/bin/go
```

now just install go and you'll be fine

Answer (score 2):

For IntelliJ or Goland user, if this happened to you in the built in terminal (but works fine in another terminal), change the go version in the settings.

`compile: version "go1.20.7" does not match go tool version "go1.21.3"`

[image: chnage go version]

then restart your IDE.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows delete the GOROOT System variables in the Enviroment Variables and restart the PC.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you use VsCode, you just add this in setting.json.

```
"go.goroot": "/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.x.x/libexec",
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, it's caused by GOROOT env, using gotip before, change to brew version.

```bash
# curret go env
cat "$(go env GOENV)"

# make sure this is correct
go env GOROOT

# unset GOROOT if setted before
go env -u GOROOT
```

you may also want to set a proper GOROOT to match the go version.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had a scripts that look like this:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.gvm/scripts/gvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.gvm/scripts/gvm"
```

Hanging around in my `.bashrc`/`.zshrc` file from a previous installation of go / trying to use gvm.

Removing this and restarting terminal solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I used getgo to update my Go version from 1.19 to 1.20. In my case, getgo created a .bash_profile and set its own export path w/c is not consistent with what's in my .bashrc.

```
#my .bash_profile;
export PATH=$PATH:/home/user/.go/bin
export PATH=$PATH:/home/user/go/bin

#my .bashrc;
export GOROOT=/usr/local/go/
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
export PATH=$PATH:$/home/user/go/bin:$GOROOT/bin:$PATH
```

SOLUTION:
I just replaced my export PATH in bashrc w/

```
export PATH=$PATH:$/home/user/.go/bin:$GOROOT/bin:$PATH
```

<Note the '.go' change w/c is now consistent to what's in my .bash_profile>.

So whether source is ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile, it will always point to the same path for Go. Hope this helps. I'm also new to Go and Ubuntu. I know how painful it is to get these variables right on your own.

Answer (score -1):

Took a simple approach(Linux),  I had different versions of Go installed in my system.

> $ whereis go

helped me to find the available go runnables, removed all, installed a fresh one and ensured to create a link for this new Go runnable in one of the $PATH folder to ensure below gives the correct version of what installed now.

> $ go version